# I received this error while trying to run the following command (PHP artisan serve) what can I do ? (BTW it's cloned from GitHub)

Tags: php, laravel, web, composer-php, artisan-serve

[the error that I encountered when I wanted to run my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhLgg.png)

Comment: Have you run `composer install` after you cloned it?

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run `composer install` or `composer update` to install all libraries first

Comment: thank you very much, previously I couldn't run this command because of the difference in my PHP version on the composer.json file. now everything is working fine, many thanks <3.

Answer (score 0):

You cloned it from **Github** so it does not have any vendor folder in it
so just run

> composer install

or

> composer update

Comment: thank you sir for the comment, previously I couldn't run this command due to the difference in my PHP version on the composer.json file. but now everything is working fine and the website is working perfectly fine